# ORA-39167: Tablespace DATA was not found

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I'm getting

```
ORA-39167: Tablespace DATA was not found.
```

when trying to run import

```
 impdp whweb10/whweb10 dumpfile=remoteexport.dmp remap_schema=company:wweb10 logfile=no directory=dump_dir table_exists_action=truncate VERSION=10.1 TABLESPACES=DATA,INDX
```

Anyway I correctly created a DATA tablespace in this way:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE "DATA" 
DATAFILE '/usr/lib/oracle/xe/oradata/XE/data.dbf'
SIZE 1024M;
```

using the user with system privileges.
Creating again the tablespace data with the whweb10 user gives me

```
ORA-01543: tablespace 'DATA' already exists
```

What can be wrong ?

Comment: did you give whweb10 a quota on DATA? (alter user whweb10 quota unlimited on data)

Comment: That's not *target* tablespace, but *source*. Are you sure that you exported data from tablespaces whose names are DATA and INDX?

Comment: Yes. I exported like this. "expdp whweb10/whweb10 directory=dump_dir dumpfile=remoteexport.dmp logfile=remoteexport.log network_link=wamaslink content=metadata_only VERSION=10.1 TABLESPACES=DATA,INDX;"